# Why does rotating UIImageView affect other UI elements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, transformation

I'm adding a background effect to my app by rotating an UIImageView using:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  rotateAngle = 0;
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(bgEffect) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) bgEffect{
  rotateAngle += .01;
  CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( rotateAngle );
  [_bgImage setTransform:rotate];
}
```

The weird problem with that is it affects some of my UI elements by shifting them. It doesn't affect all UI elements, just some. I tried to change the hierarchy, but no luck. I don't understand what the problem is. Can someone help me?

Comment: are you using constrains ?

Comment: are there any subviews in your bgImage?

Comment: How do I get rig of constraints altogether?

Comment: You can turn of Auto-Layout in your Storyboard

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem! Can you please rewrite it as the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off Auto-Layout in your Storyboard.